# IntegrityError Django Postgres when deleting

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is the error, I get it when I delete a TaskList, which is related to ChartDay which is related to MemberRemaining all with on_delete CASCADE, If a delete TaskList the Charts related to it should be deleted, same way happens with ChartDay to Chart and MemberRemaining to ChartDay. Why am I getting this error?

This is the full traceback

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 282, in _setup_and_call
    self._post_teardown()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1005, in _post_teardown
    self._fixture_teardown()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1163, in _fixture_teardown
    connections[db_name].check_constraints()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 282, in check_constraints
    cursor.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "chart_memberremaining" violates foreign key constraint "chart_memberremainin_chart_day_id_e25c792b_fk_chart_cha"
DETAIL:  Key (chart_day_id)=(2) is not present in table "chart_chartday".
```

```
class TaskList(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=get_user_model(), through='TaskListMemberShip', related_name='task_lists', blank=True
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='#ffffff', null=True)
    avatar = StdImageField(
        upload_to=FilePattern(filename_pattern='task_lists/{uuid:base64}{ext}'),
        variations={
            'normal': {'width': 200, 'height': 200, 'crop': True},
            'small': {'width': 50, 'height': 50, 'crop': True},
        },
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, related_name='task_lists', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    auto_created = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = TaskListManager()

class Chart(models.Model):
    """ Chart model. """
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    estimated = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, null=True)
    task_list = models.ForeignKey(
        TaskList, 
        related_name='charts', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ChartDay(models.Model):
    """ Chart day model. """
    date = models.DateField()
    chart = models.ForeignKey(
        Chart, 
        related_name='chart_days', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )


class MemberRemaining(models.Model):
    """ Member remaining model. """
    member = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        null=True
        )
    chart_day = models.ForeignKey(
        ChartDay, 
        related_name='members_remaining', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    remaining = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: There it is, would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I think its because you are updating member on deletion:  member = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
Ideally if chart_day is deleted then its corresponding "member" and "remaining" fields should Cascade too right?

Comment: Ideally if ChartDay is deleted then MemberRemaining should be deleted too so yeah, so when I delete TaskList then Charts, ChartDays and MemberRemainings should be deleted as well

Comment: Can you show the test you're executing when the problem occurs?